# Split text in cells at line breaks and Copying to New Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of data. In one column the texts need to be separated by a comma and split into rows.  I have a sub which works but I would like it to copy the results to a designated sheet rather than creating a new sheet. I'm not the greatest with VBA so im not sure how to manipulate the code.  Thank you in advance!

I need to be able to copy the entire sheet and place it all in another sheet (existing sheet), but with a new row for each new line in column J, as follows:

```
Column A     Column B     Column J
Electrical   Lighting     This is line one of the text
                          And in the same cell on a new line
```

This is the required result:

```
 Column A     Column B     Column J
 Electrical   Lighting     This is line one of the text
 Electrical   Lighting     And in the same cell on a new line
```

I have searched the forums for similar code, but I am having trouble adapting it for my own purpose.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM0UM.png)

```
Sub JustDoIt()
'copy to the end of sheets collection
'Worksheets("Data").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("A5", Range("A6").End(xlDown))
    If InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
        tmpArr = Split(Cell, Chr(10))
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(tmpArr),1)
        _.EntireRow.InsertlShiftDown
        Cell.Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The old code is used is:

```
Sub SplitHoursPerDay()

Dim Temp As Variant
Dim CText As String
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim L As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim lNumCols As Long
Dim lNumRows As Long

iColumn = 10

Set wksSource = Sheet4
Set wksNew = Sheet5

iTargetRow = 0
With wksSource
    lNumCols = .Range("AK1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    lNumRows = .Range("A700").End(xlUp).Row
    For J = 1 To lNumRows
        CText = .Cells(J, iColumn).Value
        Temp = Split(CText, Chr(10))
        For K = 0 To UBound(Temp)
            iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
            For L = 1 To lNumCols
                If L <> iColumn Then
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = .Cells(J, L)
                Else
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = Temp(K)
                End If
            Next L
        Next K
    Next J
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Judging by your output all you are doing is filling in the blanks in columns A and B - you are not doing anything to AJ?

Comment: OK, now think I have cottoned in. In your first example the results are on two lines in a single cell and you want to split into two cells.

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble to read what you wrote. You are referring to the 'same cell' in a new line (which can mean in the same column in  a new row. But then you are writing a new row for each new line column AJ, where I struggle to follow. Could you try to clarify by using rows and columns and refer to same cell if it has the 'same' address (row, column)?

Comment: Sorry I did not explain very well. I have columns A-AJ. the Colum I'm trying to split is column J. I have 303 rows of data. Which if split correctly will come out to close to 6000 rows. The code I had worked but it created a new sheet each time instead of copying into an existing sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. You need to specify the name of your output sheet.

```
Sub JustDoIt()

Dim tmpArr As Variant, rCell As Range, v, i As Long, v2(), j As Long, k As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Output")  'You need to specify a sheet here

v = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim v2(1 To UBound(v, 1) * 100, 1 To UBound(v, 2))
n = 1

For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    tmpArr = Split(v(i, 10), Chr(10))
    For k = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
        For j = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
            v2(n, j) = v(i, j)
        Next j
        v2(n, 10) = tmpArr(k)
        n = n + 1
    Next k
Next i

ws2.Range("A1").Resize(n, UBound(v2, 2)) = v2

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain very well. 
I have columns   A-AJ.  the Colum I'm trying to split is column J.  I have 303 rows of data. Which if split correctly will come out to close to 6000 rows. 

The code I had worked it but it created a new sheet each time instead of copying into an existing sheet.

Comment: I've amended the code above to J so try it and let me know how you get on.

Comment: I get an error message:

There isn't enough memory to complete this action.
Try using less data or closing other applications.
To increase memory availability, Consider:
  -Using a 64- bit version of Microsoft excel
 -Adding memory to your device.

I have 64 bit version and I have 16 GB Ram.

I used a different code Before this one and it worked well but recently crashed.  I add the old code to the question.

Comment: Which line errored? Can you try revised code above?

Comment: Now I'm get "Runt-time error '9': Subscript out of range"
on   v2(n, j) = v(i, j)

Comment: Worked great! Thank you! It split the 300 rows into 8000 rows in a few seconds with no errors.  This is prefect!